# How to toggle submenus in mobile and on hover in desktop using Bootstrap 5 Navbar in React.js

Tags: reactjs, navbar, bootstrap-5

I want to use `Bootstrap 5 Navbar` component in my project. It has `dropdown menus` and inside them it has `submenus`. Everything works fine in desktop and mobile. I want to open dropdown and submenus on hover in desktop and I want to open it on mobile on click. Everything is working fine as expected. But when I try to close `submenus` and `dropdown-menu` it `on mobile` again then it doesn't get close. How to close submenus and dropdown-menu on mobile using `React.js`. Please help I have wasted almost two days on it.

Main.jsx -

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App.jsx";
import "./index.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

App.jsx -

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="dvMenu">
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary">
          <div className="container-fluid">
            <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">
              Navbar
            </a>
            <button
              className="navbar-toggler"
              type="button"
              data-bs-toggle="collapse"
              data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
              aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
              aria-expanded="false"
              aria-label="Toggle navigation"
            >
              <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div
              className="collapse navbar-collapse"
              id="navbarSupportedContent"
            >
              <ul className="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <li className="nav-item">
                  <a className="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">
                    Home
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item">
                  <a className="nav-link" href="#">
                    Link
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item dropdown">
                  <a
                    className="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
                    href="#"
                    role="button"
                    data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                    aria-expanded="false"
                  >
                    Dropdown
                  </a>
                  <ul className="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>
                      <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">
                        Submenu
                      </a>
                      <ul className="submenu dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                          <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">
                            amey
                          </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">
                            rajesh
                          </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">
                            manish
                          </a>
                          <ul className="subsubmenu dropdown-menu">
                            <li>
                              <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">
                                developer
                              </a>
                              <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">
                                developer
                              </a>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">
                        adhiraj
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">
                        aldair
                      </a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item">
                  <a className="nav-link disabled" aria-disabled="true">
                    Disabled
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <form className="d-flex" role="search">
                <input
                  className="form-control me-2"
                  type="search"
                  placeholder="Search"
                  aria-label="Search"
                />
                <button className="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">
                  Search
                </button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

App.css -

```
.dvMenu .navbar-nav li {
  position: relative;
}
.dvMenu .dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
.dvMenu .dropdown-menu:hover li > .submenu {
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.dvMenu .dropdown-menu li > .submenu li:hover > .subsubmenu {
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: I have managed hover effect in desktop using CSS, but I want to toggle submenus in mobile